# How to define factory girl in rails for model that isn't in root of the models folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I would like to create a factory girl for a model in my server which is inside a folder in the models folder.

My tree view looks like:

```
├── app 
|   ├── models
│   │   ├── xxx 
│   │   |   ├── user.rb
├── spec 
│   ├── factories
│   │   ├── xxx
│   │   |   ├── user.rb
```

My factory girl looks like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    username { 'aaa' }
  end
end
```

When I try to build user I get the error:

> undefined method `new' for User:Module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your model defined under a namespace? For example, if your `app/models/xxx/user.rb` defines a class:

```
class XXX::User
  #...
end
```

Then in your factory you can do:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: XXX::User do
    username { 'aaa' }
  end
end
```