# Rails: FactoryBot does not know about the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am using Rspec and FactoryBot and I am trying to create a factory for vehicle in order to test the workflow of my app. Vehicle factory is defined below:

```
FactoryBot.define do 

  factory :vehicle do 
    vehicle_model
    fuel_type
    vehicle_body_style 
    organization_department
    vehicle_transmition
    vehicle_category
    vehicle_booking_condition  { association :vehicle_booking_condition, vehicle: instance }
    manager
    
    trait :without_booking_condition do 
      vehicle_booking_condition { nil }
    end
   
  end 
end
```

And then in my test I run this:

```
let(:operator_role)  { build(:role, name: 'operator') }
let(:manager)        { build(:user, role: operator_role) }
let(:vehicle)        { build(:vehicle, manager: manager) }
```

However, I get the following error:

NameError: uninitialized constant Vehicle
from/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `block in load_missing_constant' Caused by NameError: uninitialized constant Vehicle from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:61:in` block in load_missing_constant'

I assume it happens because I have my Vehicle model(vehicle.rb) file located in a subdirectory named write_models.(models/write_models/vehicle.rb)
Do you know how I can "inform" FactoryBot that Vehicle model is inside write_models directory?

Ok, I had done more research and found out that I can specify the exact location where the Vehicle model lies.

```
factory :vehicle, class: WriteModels::Vehicle do
```

Small change and It works fine now.Here is a link to original answer.
[How to define factory girl in rails for model that isn't in root of the models folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265122/how-to-define-factory-girl-in-rails-for-model-that-isnt-in-root-of-the-models-f)

Comment: Is the class namespaced to `WriteModels::Vehicle`? That is what Rails expects at that location.

Comment: yes it . It's inside WriteModels module.

Comment: You should add an answer instead of editing the question, could be helpful for others.